# Spark DataFrame - scala - How to group rows of a table based on timestamp with 5 minutes interval

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Cassandra Table like

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle_speed (
   device_id UUID,
   intersection text,   
   date text,
   time timestamp,
   vehicle_type text,
   speed int,
   batch_id text,
   batch_status text,   
   PRIMARY KEY ((intersection, vehicle_type), date, time)
);
```

And I have few records in the table as shown below

```
INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'ABC', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:05:00+0200', 'CAR', 45, 'PROCESSED');

INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'ABC', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:07:02+0200', 'CAR', 46, 'NEW');

INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'XYZ', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:07:00+0200', 'CAR', 52, 'NEW');

INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'ABC', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:08:30+0200', 'CAR', 44, 'NEW');

INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'ABC', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:14:30+0200', 'CAR', 40, 'NEW');

INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'XYZ', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:09:00+0200', 'CAR', 45, 'NEW');


INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'ABC', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:08:00+0200', 'BUS', 43, 'NEW');

INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'ABC', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:07:00+0200', 'BUS', 40, 'NEW');

INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'XYZ', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:08:00+0200', 'BUS', 41, 'NEW');

INSERT INTO vehicle_speed (device_id, intersection, date, time, vehicle_type, speed, batch_status) VALUES(f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf7, 'XYZ', '2016-08-28', '2016-08-28 00:08:00+0200', 'BUS', 45, 'NEW');
```

I just started learning Scala & Spark.  Can you please help me in writing code for the below use case using scala & spark?

1. Get all the rows that are not processed yet (i.e., batch_status = 'NEW')
2. Get all the rows of a particular intersection (i.e., ABC / XYZ)
3. Get all the rows of a particular  vehicle type (i.e., car / bus)
4. Get all the rows that are within 5 minutes duration (i.e., if the difference between minimum timestamp and the timestamp of other row is < 5 minutes, we need to fetch that row).
5. Calculate the average speed for all the vehicles based on the above filters (i.e., step 1 to step 5)
6. Create a new table insert the record with 5 minute aggregated time interval data.

Comment: use spark-sql and you can query the data as `Select * from table where batch_status='NEW'` or you can create RDD and use .filter api